# Unlock your Chromebook with your Android phone

Tags: 7.0-nougat, bluetooth-pairing, smart-lock, chromebook

I'm using following:

- `Huawei Nexus 6p` with `Android 7.1.2` (up-to-date).
- `ASUS Chromebook Flip` with `Google Chrome OS` (`58.0.3027.0 dev
  (32-bit)`) (up-to-date).

and I'm trying to follow: [Unlock your Chromebook with your Android phone - Chromebook Help](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/6070209?hl=en), however I'm unable to complete step #7 with following message on my Chromebook:

> Failed to connect to "Nexus 6P"

yet through "Notifications", I've got another message:

> Bluetooth device "Nexus 6P" has been paired and is now available for
>   all users. You may remove this setting using Settings.

Please advise.

Comment: If you lock ya Chromebook, there should be a lock icon? Click it, I think. Don't forget Bluetooth needs to be on.

Comment: Have you found out the answer somewhere else? I have the same problem with a new tablet now. Samsung galaxy tab. As the [bestadvisor](https://www.bestadvisers.co.uk/best-tablets) says, there are problems with connections. Disappointed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for not posting an answer in timely manner, however I'm doing it right now (that's the best I can do); As of now I'm using `Google Chrome OS` / `Version 66.0.3359.43 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)` and `Pixel`, (Phone by Google (1st generation)) w/ `Android 8.1.0`.

I went ahead and removed my Phone from Chromebook's Bluetooth devices and from Chromebook from Phone's Bluetooth devices, now that everything is tidy widy, you can proceed to next step:

under `Settings`, expand `Screen lock` (under `People`), click on `Smart Lock for Chromebook (beta)` and follow steps.